# How to prevent jumplinks from reloading the same page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I have a banner that is a video and the JavaScript extension Typed js used on the banner text on my website. I placed a jumplink right below the banner for people to automatically scroll down on the next section of the homepage. The problem is whenever that jumplink is clicked, the video restarts and as well as the JS extension. I just want it to scroll without the video restarting again or the JS extension typing out the banner text

```
<div class="section">
  <h1>SouthernLawyers</h1>
  <p><span data-controller="typed-js"></span></p>
  <a class="btn btn-gradient" href="#">Submit</a>

  <div class="video-container">
    <div class="color-overlay"></div>
      <video muted loop autoplay id="myvideo" >
         <source src ="<%= asset_path 'banner_video.mp4' %>" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
  </div>
  <a href="#about" id="down">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-down blinking"></i>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="container">
<h1 id="about">About us</h1>
<%= "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit " * 100 %>
</div>
```

Comment: That sounds indeed like the page reloads, an <a> with an href starting with a hash shouldn't cause that though. Try creating a [mre] using the `<>` button.

Answer (score -1):

Here ya go. That should be all you need! If it does not work I would try seeing if the extension you are using might be causing issues.

```css
.box {
width: 200px;
height: 700px;
}

.box-one, .box-three {
background-color: #ddd;
}

.box-two {
background-color: #000;
color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li><a href="#one">One</a></li>
 <li><a href="#two">Two</a></li>
 <li><a href="#three">Three</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="one" class="box box-one">One</div>
<div id="two" class="box box-two">Two</div>
<div id="three" class="box box-three">Three</div>
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything significantly different in  your answer to the code in the question. You haven't explained *how* it fixes the problem. (It looks like you haven't tried to identify what the problem is and have just written some code from scratch without trying to understand what the code in the question is trying to achieve).

Comment: @Quentin I gave the user a barebones clean example to test to see if  that is the intended functionality then came to the conclusion that their extension may be causing the issue. It will allow them to at least test it by taking it and adding back in the extension.

Comment: But since the code in the question doesn't exhibit the problem in the first place, that doesn't give them anything they don't already have.

Comment: @Quentin It gives them a working example outside of their environment completely. While it is something they already have, sometimes having a bit of your code in a sterile environment will allow them to debug. If OP takes my code or uses the snippet and confirms that is what they want without the current issue then they know there is something else possibly causing it and they can peel back any extensions or plugins being used. You are correct OPs code is correct. But having something sterile to compare to helps.